# Scrape website with Ruby based on embedded CSS styles

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

In the past, I have successfully used [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to scrape websites using a simple Ruby script. For a current project, I need to scrape a website that only uses inline CSS. As you can imagine, it is an old website.

What possibilities do I have to target specific elements on the page based on the inline CSS of the elements? It seems this is not possible with Nokogiri or have I overlooked something?

UPDATE: An example can be found [here](http://www.eximsystems.com/LaVerdad/Antiguo/Gn/Genesis.htm#sal002). I basically need the main content without the footnotes. The latter have a smaller font size and are grouped below each section.

Comment: If possible share the website you want to scrap?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example.

Comment: Ah, an old Word document saved as HTML. Zero structure, all inline styles. Good luck.

Comment: Give some examples of elements you want to find. Also show how you have tried to access them.

Comment: @theTinMan I have updated the question in response to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to teach you how to fish. Instead of trying to find what I want, it's sometimes a lot easier to find what I don't want and remove it.

Start with this code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

URL = 'http://www.eximsystems.com/LaVerdad/Antiguo/Gn/Genesis.htm'
FOOTNOTE_ACCESSORS = [
  'span[style*="font-size: 8.0pt"]',
  'span[style*="font-size:8.0pt"]',
  'span[style*="font-size: 7.5pt"]',
  'span[style*="font-size:7.5pt"]',
  'font[size="1"]'
].join(',')

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open(URL))
doc.search(FOOTNOTE_ACCESSORS).each do |footnote|
  footnote.remove
end

File.write(File.basename(URI.parse(URL).path), doc.to_html)
```

Run it, then open the resulting HTML file in your browser. Scroll through the file looking for footnotes you want to remove. Select part of their text, then use "Inspect Element", or whatever tool you have that will find that selected text in the source of the page. Find something unique in that text that makes it possible to isolate it from the text you want to keep. For instance, I locate footnotes using the font-sizes in `<span>` and `<font>` tags.

Keep adding accessors to the `FOOTNOTE_ACCESSORS` array until you have all undesirable elements removed.

This code isn't complete, nor is it written as tightly as I'd normally do it for this sort of task, but it will give you an idea how to go about this particular task.

---

This is a version that is a bit more flexible:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

URL = 'http://www.eximsystems.com/LaVerdad/Antiguo/Gn/Genesis.htm'
FOOTNOTE_ACCESSORS = [
  'span[style*="font-size: 8.0pt"]',
  'span[style*="font-size:8.0pt"]',
  'span[style*="font-size: 7.5pt"]',
  'span[style*="font-size:7.5pt"]',
  'font[size="1"]',
]

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open(URL))
FOOTNOTE_ACCESSORS.each do |accessor|
  doc.search(accessor).each do |footnote|
    footnote.remove
  end
end

File.write(File.basename(URI.parse(URL).path), doc.to_html)
```

The major difference is the previous version assumed all entries in `FOOTNOTE_ACCESSORS` were CSS. With this change XPath can also be used. The code will take a little bit longer to run as the entries are iterated over, but the ability to dig in with XPath might make it worthwhile for you.

Comment: This is a clever strategy that works wonders. It is time for some fishing.

Comment: It's the result of many battles against HTML in the wild, from when I was writing spiders and scrapers in Perl and people thought Word-generated HTML was the shizzle. Sometimes we need to move the rocks to see the gold.

Comment: @BartJacobs, I added a little tweak.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
doc.css('*[style*="foo"]')
```

That will select any element with `foo` appearing anywhere in it's style attribute.

Comment: not understood the difference between `[style*="foo"]'` and `[style ="foo"]'`

Comment: Why don't you read the doc I pointed you to and then tell me?

Comment: @pguardiario This works surprisingly well. However, I have a better hit/mis ratio with the Tin Man's approach, which is why I accepted his answer. Thanks for your help.